List of tables with count of records present in those tables from sysibm in DB2
Is there a way to determine the total number of records of all the persistent tables from sysibm. I tried the below query however CARD does not match the total count of that particular table.
SELECT name, TYPE, CARD, STATS_TIME FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES where name='XXX'


You can assemble a query using Dynamic SQL based on the result of that query and then run it to could the number of rows of each table a simple stored proc would do.

The number may differ as these data are only updated with runstats so it is usable as a rough idea or you try to do this right after you executed a runstats

The SYSIBM.SYSTABLES.CARD column only gets updated when the runstats utility completes successfully for the table(s) concerned.
The value in CARD is therefore an estimate and on a busy database with high inserts/deletes, it can be incorrect moments after it gets updated.
So , understand carefully your real need to know the precise count for all persistent tables. If it is a static databases (nothing is changing) then a runstats for all tables will be useful (without sampling), although if terabytes of data are involved then this can cost a lot of I/O and CPU.
Instead of depending on runstats, you can also use an anonymous block to dynamically perform the select count(...) for the tables of interest, in a loop. This may also take quite some time and cost a lot of I/O.
That's the reason you need to fully understand the need for precise row-counts for every persistent table, and how ephemeral such counts can be in a non-static busy database.
